# View UI how to set DatePicker week start day on Monday

Tags: iview, iview-ui

Now it defaults to Sunday, but I need to set it to Monday

[View UI](http://v4.iviewui.com/components/date-picker-en)

I searched for a long time but couldn't find the answer

Comment: This issue seems to fix and merged, visit https://github.com/iview/iview/pull/1997, and try to play with the locale setting on View UI.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has solved my problem. My project introduced ViewUI through CDN, but I am a little curious, how to change it if it is a Vue CLI project.